# how to do the condition in magento?

Tags: php, magento

there are some code as this:

```
    <div class="test">
        <div class="upsell-tags"> 
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to add a if condition before the `<div class="test">`. how do i do? thank you.
when i add the following code, it shows me an error,. why?

```
<?php if(isset($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'))):?>.....


    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PHP docs:

> **Warning**
>
> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

You're passing the return value of a function, which isn't a valid use. You'll need to do something like

```
$upsell = $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products');
if($upsell) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the magento code, the function getChildHtml return a string.

```
/**
 * Retrieve child block HTML
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   boolean $useCache
 * @param   boolean $sorted
 * @return  string
 */
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
```

If you look a bit more, it seem that the function return an empty string if there is nothing to render. So I would just display the returned html without any condition. If you really need to know if there is something, I would do: if ($this->getChildHtml($name) != '')